# How to implement interval scheduling algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, intervals, schedule, greedy

I am asked to:

Angusina is attending the Christchurch Buskers Festival and wants to see as many shows as she can on a given day. She has a list of all the shows in an arbitrary order. Each one is a tuple with a title, a start time (conveniently specified in minutes from midnight) and a duration, also in minutes. Help Angusina decide what shows to attend.

Write a function print_shows(show_list) that takes a list of show tuples as defined above and prints in order of start time the list of shows that Angusina should attend, as obtained using the algorithm in the lecture notes. Shows are printed one per line with the title, start and end times separated by a space as shown in the example. To ensure a unique solution, you may assume that show end times are unique.

This is the pseudocode I must use:

```
Sort jobs by finish times: f1 <= f2 <=...fn

S = {}

t_current = 0   (Finish time of the last job selected)

for j = 1...n:

    if sj >= t_current:

        S = S U {j}

        t_current = fj

return S
```

My test code is:

print_shows([
('a', 0, 6),
('b', 1, 3),
('c', 3, 2),
('d', 3, 5),
('e', 4, 3),
('f', 5, 4),
('g', 6, 4),
('h', 8, 3)])

My result should be:

b 1 4

e 4 7

h 8 11

I am not sure how to read the pseudocode?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer you need. Basically, you sort by finish time (start time + duration), then you loop through the elements in the list, if the start time is after the current finish time, it is added to the attend list and the current finish time is updated. That's it more or less.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this site can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") and ["How do I ask and answer homework questions?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions "How do I ask and answer homework questions?") pages for details on how to best help us help you.